# Should I tell my interviewer I am being interviewed by other people at the same company?

Tags: interviewing, recruitment

I applied to 4 different positions directly on the company site and I am currently being interviewed for 2 of those positions by the same recruiter and different managers. A second recruiter just invited me to an interview for the third position I applied for.

They are all software engineering positions, but with different teams such as Mobile app team and Web team.

Should I tell the recruiters / managers about everyone I am currently in the interview process with?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Should I let the recruiters / managers about everyone I am currently
>   in the interview process with?

Yes.

**Scenario 1:**: you tell them and they already know. This simply enhances your reputation being as "honest and transparent"

**Scenario 2:**: You tell them and they don't know: You enhance your reputation even more, since they can now sort this out earlier in the game and potentially avoiding a mess later on, so you really helped. It's also good for you to know that the company is rather disorganzied.

**Scenario 3:**: You DON'T tell them and they don't know. This can get messy down the line, if both are making an offer and you turn one down for the other, this can kick of some real awkwardness and bad blood between the departments. It's their fault, but you are still caught in the middle of it

**Scenario 4:**: You DON'T tell them and they do know. You just come across as a sub-optimal communicator. They may be wondering why you don't bring it up or ask about it "What happens if I get two offers?" or something like this.

Comment: Absolutely, honesty and clear communication is paramount.

Comment: "Sub-optimal communicator" now that's a phrase to remember

Comment: @Naz "Sub-optimal" is a great substitute when "Shitty" does not fit the general tone of the discussion.

Comment: Your point is really correct, however I had a similar situation. I was interviewing with one department I was not really interested in, and when second department which had a really interesting job description invited me, I informed them about the situation. The second department said "Oh well, we do not duplicate our invitations, first conclude the other interview", and the first department DID NOT give a clear yes / not for months.

Answer (score 0):

Assume they know. You can assume this because they are likely using a system that allows them to see the other applications you currently have or had submitted previously.

So if they ask, tell them about the other applications with the some company. I wouldn't even hesitate telling them.

Some teams may be concerned that you are too far along with the other applications, and hesitate to invest more company time interviewing, but if that is the case trying to hide it doesn't help your odds of getting hired.

One thing they will try to avoid is competing against themselves. I know that it is typical for a company require you to dropout of consideration for any other positions with their company as soon as you accept the job offer.

Now if the recruiter, hiring manager, or interviewer asks about applications with other companies, you have no obligation to tell them.

Comment: This sounds very reasonable. Would you suggest that I let the first recruiter know as well (via email) or to only bring it up if I have another interview / conversation with the person?

Answer (score -1):

My 2 cents_
Don’t tell them unless they are asking you. It raises various internal issues and speculations that you should be preserved from.

It’s always time to tell it on final interviews or if they are asking.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).